# Display Fragment Onclick

Tags: android

I have the error in line

> FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

Any solution for pass activities when I click? So what I need?

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

private List<ItemObject> itemList;
private Context context;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.cardText.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
    holder.cardPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:

                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new FragmentNewGame(), "newGame");
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this :

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

to this :

```
FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

Then your code should look like :

```
FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new FragmentNewGame(), "newGame");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Or

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new FragmentNewGame(), "newGame");
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: With a quick google seems like `getFragmentManager` is an `Activity` method ... - haven't done Android/Java for ages but his might work

Comment: [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager()) indicates that `getFragmentManager` belongs to Activity and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) indicates that `RecyclerView.Adapter` does not inherit Activity... so your solution seems correct. However, I have not coded on Android for 2-3 years... and I am not sure...

Comment: Ah, don't worry, I faced with the same problem months ago, and I solved it doing this, let's see if it works for him :D